# for loop: range(sth) that sth is increasing. is it wrong?

Tags: python, loops, range

```
for j in xrange(len(self.segments)):
    *
    ***some code here*** 
    *
    if (****condition*****):
        self.segments.append(segB)
```

So, i have a for loop and xrange(self.segments) where self.segments is incrising! 
do you think there is a problem?

Comment: Whether there's a problem depends on whether you *want* to iterate over the newly added elements.

Comment: It's not wrong, per se, but it's generally bad practice to modify a list while looping over it.

Answer (score 4):

You won't iterate over the indices that correspond to the elements that you have added because `xrange` is evaluated when the loop *starts*.  It doesn't get re-evaluated after that.

Whether or not this is wrong depends entirely on what you're trying to do.  If you want to iterate over the list's elements (and you want to catch the ones that you're adding as well), then you can probably get away with:

```
for item in self.segments:
    #...
    if whatever:
        self.segments.append(segB)
```

This is because lists iterate in a predictable way.  This only works since you're adding to the end of the list -- It wouldn't necessarily work if you `.insert` data somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @MariaKaragewrgiou -- This really depends entirely on what you're trying to do.  If you actually *need* to loop over the indices, then yes, a `while` loop is probably what you want -- something like the following loop `while idx < len(self.segments)` is what I would probably use.